# Should I block agent Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)?

Tags: seo, htaccess, web-crawlers, googlebot

Is that a scraper? It tried accessing my site which is currently password protected for testing purposes. shall I block it?

Comment: You cannot block all the scrapers. Tons of them...

Comment: Yeah. But we are getting very close.

Comment: You know that pretty much every user agent can be spoofed right?

Comment: Of course. But agent names are garbage data. The statement was *you cannot block all the scrapers* and I replied that we are getting closer.

Answer (score 13):

Wget is just a command line tool for linux that fetches resources over HTTP - all this tells you is that someone accessed your site via a command line, it could have been a bot scraping you, but there's no way of knowing for sure

If your site is password protected properly, there shouldn't be any need to block particular user agents :) x

Comment: And of course, `wget` lets the user set the `User-Agent` string (it's the `-U` / `--user-agent` option), so blocking `wget`'s default user-agent string is almost entirely useless.

Comment: It's password protected for experimenting, soon I want to make it public, and would rather have as less scrapers as possible, so if I caught that one in advance, I think it would be good to block it on .htaccess before making the site public, wouldn't it?

Comment: If the page is going to be public, you're not going to be able to stop all scrapers (as @T.J.Crowder pointed out it's easy for them to disguise their useragent anyway). If something is public, it's public - why would you want to block people accessing the content?

Comment: I'm afraid that somehow a scraper would get my content indexed before me, and thus make my site look duplicate, or any other similar SEO concern

Comment: Keep in mind that Google uses bots to crawl pages too, so not all bots are bad :) You won't be able to stop people downloading your content if it's public - if you block wget people will just change its user agent, or just open up a web browser and download it themselves. This is very unlikely harm your SEO as your site will be most up to date, and Google is very clever. If you're *really* concerned about this, submit your site to Google Webmaster tools when you publish it - that'll give you stats about what the Googlebot thinks about your site etc x

Answer (score 5):

wget has legitimate uses, yes, but it's also quite useful for Web scraping.  However, I don't think you should try to block it (or any other agent) by using the user agent string.

wget respects, by default, your robots.txt file.  It's true that a scraper can just switch that option off, but guess what -- it's just as easy to use `--user-agent MSIE(blahblah)` and impersonate Internet Explorer if you start blocking at the HTTP level.  I've written scraping scripts before and you'd better believe changing the UA is one of the first steps (if that doesn't work you could always switch gears and simply write a script to automate IE, of course).

If you're really concerned, you'll need to try and catch bot-like *behavior* -- pages without referrers, too many requests in too short a time, etc.  However, I'm afraid you'll quickly find that it's pretty trivial for someone who wants to scrape your site to bypass any measure you could possibly take (short of those that would be too onerous to your users, like only allowing one page view per hour or something).  This is also likely to be a big time sink.

Essentially, if legitimate users can see your page, there's not much you can do to keep scrapers from seeing it too.

Answer (score 1):

wget is often used for scraping. It's a command-line tool to download webpages and their assets. If your website isn't being publicized, you can almost be sure that it's a bot doing scraping. So yes, you could block it, but also be aware you may need to do something more sophisticated than blocking it with robots.txt since wget can easily be told to ignore robots.txt

To this particular user agent in .htaccess, you could add the following:

```
BrowserMatchNoCase Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu) wget
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=wget
```

Comment: Do you know what's the appropriate command to add to .htaccess to block all these Wget ?

Comment: how do I hate this answer, let me count the ways: wget is not a linux tool it is a gnu tool and was written for unix and has been ported to every major operating system including OSX and Windows. wget isn't the best tool for scraping, it is barley adequate at best (it is very useful for mirroring and is also used as a dowloader for uzbl). Your certainty that it is scraping is great, can you prove it or are you just right? wget respects the robots.txt file except on single file downloads as documented in the man page.

Comment: @hildred How is "mirroring" a site or "downloading" a web page not "scraping"? The intention of the question was not to determine weather it's a GNU/Linux tool, it's what it's purpose is. It's not a typical web browser, and nobody is trying to navigate to his site with wget to view it as a human. Have you ever used wget to browse the web? Didn't think so. And no, I can't "prove" that it's scraping the website, but like I said nobody uses wget to browse the web, so it's the most likely conclusion.

Comment: @hildred you can also ignore robots.txt with the -e robots=off flag with wget. But again, thanks for "hating" my answer without providing any useful constructive criticism.

Comment: @getbuck I've added code to block that user-agent string in .htaccess

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht thanks, shouldn't it be though something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR] ` ? I found this code in [this guide](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml)

Comment: @getbuck ya, that'll work too. Two different ways of achieving the same goal. Though if you're going to be blocking more than just this one bot, your way will be easier to maintain since you don't need to specify different version #s, etc.

Comment: does mine include a wildcard that blocks all versions? what character signifies that wildcard? and btw @hildred WGET doesn't ask for robots.txt, checked my sever logs

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht I looked hard to find something to help your answer as originally written and the number of errors outnumbered anything of worth by such a wide margin anything worth encouraging was lost. I did point you to the manpage.

Comment: @gitbuck, wget does not check for robots.txt if it is just downloading a single file, which is normaly a legitimate use.

Comment: ... and the reason for that is that `robots.txt` contains instructions for spiders. Downloading a single url is not spidering. From http://www.robotstxt.org/, "Web Robots (also known as Web Wanderers, Crawlers, or Spiders), are programs that traverse the Web automatically". Downloading a single URL provided by a user is not traversing automatically, but `wget --recursive` is (and checks for robots.txt by default).

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht "Have you ever used wget to surf the web?" Yes, actually, I have. Not by itself, but we've no real indication here that whomever was using wget was using only wget and nothing else. depending on my net connection and what hardware i was using, I've occasionally used wget in conjunction with a regular browser to view pages under conditions in which just browsing by using a browser normally would be infeasible due to tons of time-outs and the like. Each time I wanna follow a link, i just tell wget to try til it gets it, then read what i've already got til that page's available.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I read questions like this I think of Kevin Spacey's character in Henry and June. The fellow who was always writing his greatest Novel, but was so worried about someone stealing his ideas he kept it locked away in a briefcase, carried close to his chest...

Every linux user is a "legit" wget user. I use it often for grabbing debs, videos, binaries, whatever. It's easy to drive from the command line so, yeah, it makes a great scraper. But that's definitely not its only use, and making it appear as firefox or msie is just one --parameter away, so you're wasting your time blocking it. If anything, if you do that you're going to attract the attention of anyone passing by; they'll change the user-agent string and start digging for what you have "hidden."

Comment: You half made my point for me. You are right. The agent name can be changed easily. But still, this does not mean that WGet should or should not be blocked. It is a single small step in securing against a site from abuse. Other steps have to be taken too. I advised that blocking the agent depends upon your user. I too use  WGet periodically as you say you do. But I am sure you use it against sites that expect it to be used and not content only sites like blogs and such where people count on their content for revenue. It is a personal decision plain and simple.

Answer (score -1):

Why another answer? Because both are right but with caveats. I study these things as a subject area regarding security.

WGet is an offline web browser. It is not interactive like Linx which is a text based browser that works something like any other browser. WGet is most often used to capture resources such as downloads, videos, audio files and capture and create a localized copy of a website. It can be used by scrapers, but it would awkward to do and would require hand written code to parse files. I have done this for customers. I would not recommend it.

WGet is not a scraping tool. It is generally not used by scrapers directly because there are so many software scrapers out there that it would not make sense. However, the use of WGet does allow the user to do things that would not otherwise happen. For example, I can create a resource URL corrected version of a page, part of a site, or whole site, to browse offline off of my hard drive. It is possible for WGet to download a page, part of a site, or whole site corrected for redeployment somewhere else. But from my experience, this does not happen.

WGet is not generally a tool that anyone really needs to do work against *your* site.

And that is exactly my point. Anyone using WGet is not a casual user and often has something nefarious in mind. But not always. I have used WGet to download research papers, data, and any other resources where I would have to click a bunch of links essentially one at a time and pay attention to the process. For example, I could specify what page to look at, and what resources I wanted to download and I could trigger it to run on my robot server completely unattended. I use WGet for valid work. But users like myself are extremely rare, and I would not be using it against your site without your knowing it.

I would block this agent. I have it blocked on all the sites I control. If you are not offering downloads videos, audio files, e-books, and other similar resources for open downloading, block this agent. The user is likely up to no good. In fact, during my study, outside of a resource site, I have not seen a valid WGet user.

Comment: This is an aristocratic answer. "I am a legitimate user of wget, but you peasant are a no good nefarious user of wget and should be blocked."

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say. I am simply trying to explain valid uses for WGet and that there are valid users, but not generally for most sites and situations. I am also saying that while there are valid uses, my experience from a security perspective is that I have yet to see WGet used against a non-resource site as being valid. I track security issues and users and can say that WGet is often seen from bad neighborhoods and bad users almost exclusively. If you are trying to paraphrase my response negatively, you have severely missed the mark.

Comment: unless I misread your answer it boils down to "I (a researcher) use wget in a legitimate fashion but people (users) don't" and since there are more users than researchers block it. The two problems with this argument are that it throws the baby out with the bathwater, by blocking legitimate uses of wget like yourself and that it encourages the myth of the division the population on the other side of the wire into two categories of behavior: expected and prohibited. This squashes the important category of the unexpected, which is often quite valuable. as to where I was directing my answer (cont

Comment: (continued) I was aiming at the dark hole that was the result of your mindset which I have seen lead to oppression. I know that my paraphrasing of your answer is not your intent but it is the result of your argument.

Comment: I suspect you have clouded your perception just a bit. I was careful to illustrate valid uses for WGet and that there are valid users but that they are not casual users or web browsers. I was also careful to note that I did not use WGet except for special circumstances and with the site owners knowledge except in cases where WGet is normal use for downloading resources often on EDU sites or other open resource sites. In my *many* years of researching security issues, there has not been a case where WGet has showed up in the log files where the usage was less than suspect.

Comment: I will keep this simple. Yes there are valid uses and valid users but the realm in which they live does not cross the everyday website. It has been my experience that for most sites, WGet is used by bad people and should be blocked, unless your site is a resource site where you wish people to access your resources using WGet.

Comment: I saw how carefully you draw that line in the sand, right around your thumb (but there was one thing you left vague and that was why you would provide a webserver that does not serve web pages -resources, by definition), and then you make the argument that although you have used wget for legitimate purposes that you haven't seen any one else do so. This argument is blind at best.

Comment: Hardly. If you ran a blog, then there are no reasons for WGet hitting your site. None at all. If you are providing resources such as Cert/NVD in the way of XML files, then it expected that WGet will be used to download the files. A resource site is specific in that it provides resources not to be confused with the term in a programming context.

Comment: I think this answer gives totally the wrong impression of both wget and how data on the internet is shared. If you have made a web resource public, it is public. It is not up to you to decide "I'll let Chrome users download it, but I won't let wget users view it". You can't casually say "there are no reasons for wget hitting your site". You certainly don't need to get the webmasters permission to use wget. People should be free to use open data as they please - if you have such issues with how people use data, they shouldn't be on public facing pages.

Comment: And a big amen to @EmilyShepherd, she sees the same problem from an entirely different point of view. and shows how useless your assertion that resource has a different meaning in programming.

Comment: In extension to my point above, I also believe you've missed various aspects of the web - the semantic elements of HTML5, microdata, microformats, RDF: all examples of how html pages *can* (and should!) be semantic enough to parse for information if people want it. Screen readers, translators, custom blogs with pingbacks are some of the most obvious uses for accessing a page not via a web browser. Maybe people might use wget for those things, maybe they wouldn't - but blanket blocking anything that "has no reason for being there" will lead to needlessly making legitimate tasks harder.

Comment: so @closetnoc, you don't want me reading your blog? my typical workflow for serious blog reading is to download the interesting and thought provoking articles, convert them to epubs and read them in the park where I have the quiet to read them and understand them.

Comment: I do not live in a theoretical world. If I were a carpenter, I could use a hammer, nail gun, or pneumatic hammer to drive a nail. Two of these are appropriate for the task, and one is very inappropriate. WGet has it's purposes, but is not a casual browser tool for most users of websites. In fact, most of the time, it is used for nefarious purposes. I block WGet. It is not an appropriate tool to access the sites I control. But it could be an appropriate tool for some sites. I was even careful to give a good example of where it would be appropriate. I will not argue theory. I will argue facts.

Comment: WGet is not for reading blogs offline though it can be used to download local copies of a site in part or in whole. It is also not a parser nor likely to be used for that. There are tools for these functions. On the whole, I look at use and misuse of websites everyday. If you want to run an open everything goes site, then go for it. If you need to protect your site from content theft, then I suggest considering blocking WGet as a part of your strategy. I am not suggesting blocking WGet for every site all the time. I am suggesting that you consider it and under what circumstances.

Comment: But you are arguing theory! You seem to believe that because *you* wouldn't use wget for something, *no-one* would, or even worse no-one should. That misses the point of open data. Maybe wget isn't the best tool for read later blogs, maybe it's not the best tool to pipe HTML into a screenreader. But I suggest to you that you "consider it under what circumstances" - maybe sometimes it *is* the best for a particular chain of tools, or its the fastest to use to get the desired job done, or it is the worst but someone does it anyway. If you need to block wget, your data shouldn't be public at all.

Comment: Have a read of the analogy at http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/ which says *exactly* what you've said about wget - it says that PHP is not the appropriate tool for the job. But then go ahead and look at how many people disagree with that opinion (myself included :) ) and use PHP everyday. "I wouldn't use $x for this job" does NOT mean "No One would use $x for this job" and it certainly shouldn't mean "I should try to stop people using $x for this job"

Comment: Are you equating WGet o PHP? I am not. That would be ridiculous.  WGet, for those who do not know, is a bulk website download tool though it can be selective too. I am not arguing theory at all. There is a reason why WGet is one of the most widely blocked user agents. It is not a browser, a parser, a reader, or anything else. It is often used for nefarious purposes. I also noted that there are valid reasons to allow WGet and cited one. I am not an absolutist as you seem to reacting. My advise is exactly what I stated. I recommend blocking it for most sites but not all. You decide. Simple.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that I went over to your website on Chrome and, while browsing, was blocked twice as either a bot or blacklisted IP. As it was intermittent I'm assuming it wasn't a blacklisted IP (also I'm at home, so that'd be weird if it were) so I'm assuming my, very human, behaviour was enough to have me categorised as a bot. Blocking like that simply doesn't work and it prevents legitimate people from doing legitimate things.

Comment: As a side note, read the other answers. Two of the three concur with the notion that WGet is used for content scraping. I was a bit kinder by noting that there are valid uses for WGet while noting that WGet most of the time is not used for valid purposes. I deal with security research everyday. If you naively believe that WGet is a tool generally seen in your log files for legitimate purposes and a normal part of the *open data* paradigm, you are sorely mistaken.

Comment: In answer to your question: yes I am comparing the two. PHP is often used for nefarious purposes too, but we don't attack it because that'd be silly. PHP is also dismissed as something that they wouldn't use for web sites, and yet people use it for web sites. So how come your dismissal of wget is any different? If I wanted to read blogs later, I almost certainly would use wget - it's easy, it's there, it gets the job done. Why shouldn't I use it if it works?

Comment: When I build a site, I build it securely; everything that I'm happy to be public is public. Everything that I want protect is behind authentication - I DO NOT dictate *how* they work with the data I've given them rights to. Anything I publish on a public site, I would be happy for someone to download. Why shouldn't I be? It's PUBLIC. Maybe someone that does consider themself a hacker or a bot downloads it, so what? It was public, what harm does that do?

Comment: In response to your side note: the score is currently 11 to -1 (12-0) in favour of not blocking wget.

Comment: I am sorry for that. The website has historically existed to gather behavioral patterns. I can say, that I hit the site every day with Chrome with no troubles. It may be that the site is not detecting normal browser patterns; images, JS, cookies, access speed, access patterns, etc. which may need to be adjusted. Not enough of these and you are blocked. It is a part of gauging the limits of normal user behavior verses bot behavior. It was rolled out just a bit ago and the limits have not all been discovered yet.

Comment: But that score is not reflected in real world practices. Sorry. But WGet is overwhelmingly blocked universally all over the world and for good reasons. Again, I am not arguing an absolutist point. I recommend *considering blocking* for the reasons that I have stated and allowing it if you please. I am not a *hater* but a realist. Sorry if that is not your experience.

Comment: The web follows a lot of bad practice. We are both experienced enough to know what most uneducated web developers do and what is best practice are almost mutually exclusive ;) x

Comment: I remember when content scraping was not an issue. I prefer an open web. I am working on tracking network usage patterns of hackers and incidentally web site abusers. I include web site issues because it is an under-served community. I actually dropped a lot of blocks from my one site recently because the bot blocker works. It is a bit too aggressive - I agree. I get anywhere from 10-1 to 100-1 user/scraper bot activity per day partly because I put bait out. I envision a day where the user agent is never even discussed because it does not matter anymore. See! We are on the same side! ;-)

Comment: @closetnoc I don't know where you're finding enough wget-blocking websites to qualify as "overwhelmingly blocked universally", maybe we just prefer different kinds of sites with different cultures to the people who create them, but I've used wget on an awful lot of sites, and I've been blocked for it exactly zero times, ever.

Comment: I used to be in the webhost business. As well, I consulted to the major telecoms and supported nearly 1000 web servers with many sites on each. Note that these were not individual sites, but corporate sites. As well, I have consulted for many companies on their Internet presence over the years. WGet is one of the very first agents blocked from my experience and I have been at this longer than you can imagine. I am speaking from my experience. Also note that I conceded that there are sites that are open to WGet because of the nature of what they offer. There is a divide.